# Using Mercurial (hg) to keep track of changes and synchronize automatically?

Tags: mercurial, synchronization, dvcs

First off, I've been staring at page after page of solutions but none of them seem to fit the situation I have.

I have web developers all around the country using Windows workstations with Eclipse.  We decided DVCS was best for us because the centralized system just isn't working (Serena: slow network connections takes forever to check in... they don't do it because it's not "streamlined", etc.)

We use Eclipse to edit and modify files on a development server in a different state.  (Most DVCS scenarios assume you have a web server setup on your workstation or are doing binary executable development.)

What I'd like to try is to have a local repository for developer changes and "feature play" but automatically keep the development repository up to date.  I thought of using Mercurial hooks to automatically pull/update/merge/push but that requires the developer to commit every time they want to test a change.  (in order to fire the hook to upload their file to the development server.)  It would be ideal to have this automatically happen on file saves because it's already an issue with training people to use version control (mainly because it's PITA slow currently with the WAN and virtual locations.  Getting the WAN upgraded is not an option.)

My guess is that I'm going to have to setup Unison or something to keep the developer's repository synced to the development server as if it were a local copy and that of course would sync with the other developers.  I was trying to find out if anyone had a solution that's streamlined/simple for keeping all developers up to date while allowing them to version control at will (easily.)

Comment: At some point a developer has to say "I am happy with that" and that is what a commit is. That is the essence of version control, and there is no avoiding it. Doing commits on file saves (if that is what I understand you to be suggesting) is insanity.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I assume we're going to have to setup a synchronization solution in order to do this.  Placing a development environment on every workstation is not feasible in our situation.

Comment: Sorry, but that's just a cop out.  I don't care if your webapp is a front end for a space based laser and requires a software piece with a $50,000 seat-license -- you can and should mock it up for per-developer on-desk testing.  "Let's see if this work on the far away server" was our sad lot in life 10 year ago, but there's no need to take that _huge_ productivity hit these days. Use VMs or Mocks or spend $10K for each dev; whatever it costs in time and dollars will be made up in real productivity gains.

Comment: The thing is, Mercurial is meant as a tool that plugs into other best-practice ways of doing things. You have a bad process overall, no matter how good Mercurial is it won't save you from problems. As @Ry4an says, you *really* should have a local test environment for each developer. Let me rephrase this. To try to wring one tool to fit a bad process just makes the process worse, and all advice you're going to get is going to try to drag you away from that. Let me rephrase again. If you ask for advice on SO, you *will* keep hearing that you need a local test environment.

Comment: Yeah, I understand it's a bad process.  I have no control over that directly and don't think I can get it changed.  I'm just trying to get ideas to make it more sane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what branches are for. Have a branch called "unstable" and set your development server up with a repository that auto-updates on commits/merges to *only* that branch (via hook). Individual developers are free to work on feature branches and commit locally. When something is ready to be shared, the developer merges their changes into the "unstable" branch and pushes that branch to the development server/repository.

I manage my deployments this way. My Web server virtual host web root points to a Mercurial repository/working copy. When something is ready to go out, I merge it into the "stable" branch and push "stable" to the server. The repository hook updates the files on the virtual host with the new changes.

```
[hooks]
changegroup = /usr/bin/hg update stable >&2
```

I've only been doing this for a month or so but it's been working like a charm.

Also, +1 on checking out Hudson/Jenkins. What you're looking for is called "continuous integration" (CI) and Hudson and Jenkins make that happen.

If you can't have a development server on all workstations, then maybe using Test Driven Development with some sort of Unit Test framework for your language would work - most of those don't require a full server implementation to be able to write and test your code. It would require a change in paradigm but you'd sure get better quality of code out of that.

Comment: This is a neat concept, but it still runs into the problem with the developers not being able to test locally (no framework locally to test their code against...) It gives me a few ideas on some other aspects though, so thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0):

We're very happy with mercurial, but we had to change our habits... and it took some time

Each dev has now a test platform locally. Commits are made through branches and nothing is pushed before tests have been validated locally

Then, Hudson is our friend. To integrate teams works, each commit results in a build that tests the integrity of the app. Red signify rollback and return to the dev. Green is cool

Devs are here to commit 'sane' code and integrate by team to the central repo. They must decide when it's the time to push. No synchronized task can deliver them from this burden. When I see all the errors that can happen, even if each push choice is made consciensciouly by a human, I can't imagine if changes happened automatically on each file save

Good experience with Mercurial...

Comment: "Each dev has now a test platform locally." - 
This is something we cannot do.  We work on a framework and on distinct modules on the development server so having a local dev environment would mean replicating tons of data in local SQL servers, authentication, licenses... not going to happen.

Comment: that are restricted test platform, with unit tests & integration tests per module. That's not the entire platform. But that's not the point. Each organization is different, mine is not a perfect model. That was just an experience of how Mercurial changed our habits and helped us to improve our process. But constraints exist, for sure.

Comment: "replicating tons of data in local SQL Servers" is a giveaway. You might want to seriously consider Test Driven Development, and using some sort of mocking/stubbing framework. You don't need a local database to do that, and integration testing can occur on your development server with your real data as you do it now.

Comment: The development is done on "modules" of a broader page.  The modules need the framework of the site to run.  The framework handles login, session information, etc.  The data includes locations, user information, etc.

The testing framework that would be needed for that would be a pretty massive undertaking and keeping that up to date when core, CSS or other changes occur on the framework is not something that is going to occur.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you want to have a local repository for developer changes, but automatically push any changes to the server. If you cannot have a local dev environment to test changes on, what is the point of having local development branches? If your testing must be done on the development server, there is no way I can think of to allow for "feature play" in local repositories while maintaining any kind of sanity on your development server.

Your best bet in this scenario would probably be branching on the development server and having the server checkout different branches to test different features (hg update -C feature-blah). The default state for the server's repository should be a checkout of the main "devel" branch (hg update -C devel), and when any features or bugfix branches are verified as working they are merged back into "devel" and the server's repository updated from that.

Edit to clarify: your developers would either checkout from "devel" or from a feature branch to their local machine. They would then make any edits and push it back up to the server, and then switch the server's active branch to the newly-updated code.

Also, I am assuming from your other comments that there is only one dev server and it is only able to run one version of the code at a time. If this is not the case, my answer makes no sense at all.

Comment: Yeah, one dev server.  Luckily all the devs normally do not work on the same files so conflicts are minimal, but it would be nice to have some sort of conflict resolution.  Thus the local repository with the working branch being synced to the server.  If there was an overwrite, you still have your local.  Sorry for the confusion.  I understand it would literally be impossible to have two devs working on the same page on different features at the same time with only one server.  I don't know if I'd be interested in having the dev server checking out content on a regular basis.

Comment: For conflict resolution, that's what merging is for. Mercurial will automatically figure out how to combine changesets. With the described method, you still have your past revisions to revert to if something goes wrong, and experimental changes would be done on a feature branch anyway so you still have the semi-stable devel branch to switch back to. As far as the dev server "checking out", with a DVCS like Mercurial switching branches is fast and trivial. You may want to familiarize yourself more thoroughly with how DVCS works to find the best solution for your workflow.